# Django admin page raises the "Please correct the errors below” error without pointing to the field that causes it

Tags: python, django

I was able to successfully extended the user model. I can store the date into the database using forms. However, when I try to modify and save the field values from Django's admin page it show the *"Please correct the errors below”* error. But it doesn't shows where the error is. I have tried some of the solutions suggested here but I couldn't resolve the problem. BTW, I am using Mongodb and Djongo as my database.

**models.py**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(blank=True, null=True)
    country = CountryField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as BaseUserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from register.models import Profile

# to show the user profile in the django admin page
class UserProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = "details"


class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)



# to re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**forms.py**

```
class UserForm(UserCreationForm):

    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]


class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    # gender = GenderField()
    country = CountryField(blank_label='(select country)').formfield()
    phone_no = PhoneNumberField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ["phone_no", "country"]
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        user_form = UserForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user_instance = user_form.save()
            prof_instance = profile_form.save(commit=False)
            prof_instance.user = user_instance
            prof_instance.save()
            return redirect("/")

    else:
        user_form = UserForm()
        profile_form = ProfileForm()

    return render(request, "register/register.html", {"user_form": user_form, "profile_form": profile_form})
```

**form template**

```
<form method="POST" class="form-group">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ user_form|crispy }}
            {{ profile_form|crispy }}
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Register</button>
        </form>
```

---

**Update 1**

As can been the data has been inserted into the db and can be view in the admin page.
[image: the value of the fields]

But when I try to change the values (let's say the phone number) and press the save button is shows the following message. No error is logged on the screen.
[image: error message in the admin page]

Comment: Can you please include your screenshot of the error message and the admin dashboard into your question?

Comment: A tip: Run the django server, insert it after profile_form `breakpoint()` and post the data. Check if form is valid typing `user_form.is_valid()` and `profile_form.is_valid()` one of them must return `False` with false result type `profile_form.errors` and you will see what's going wrong. If you're using python3.6 the breakpoint() method doesn't work so replace it for `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`.

Comment: I have added the screenshots. @DiegoMagalhães problem is in the admin page not the forms.py. So, I am not sure how to add the `breakpoint()` in the app so that the value of the admin fields are shown.

Comment: The email field is missing in change user page

Answer (score 0):

There is an email field in your User model.

```
class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["username", "email", "password1", "password2"]
```

In change user page the error appears because there is something wrong in the email field that isn't present and therefore doesn't point out the error.

You need to add `fieldsets` and `add_fieldsets` in `UserAdmin` according to [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin).

For example:

```
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('name', 'email', 'password',)}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {    
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2'),
            }),
        )
    inlines = (UserProfileInline,)
```

Comment: Thank you @DiegoMagalhães but it didn't resolve the issue. The same problem persists...is there anyway to debug the admin dashboard?